# How to restore DNS being automatically obtained?

Tags: wireless, 16.04, dhcp

After a reboot I can no longer connect to the internet in the sense that it appears DNS lookups immediately fail.

I am connecting via WiFi to my phone, which works as a dongle (I have no landline available right now).

The phone can access the internet - I am writing on it now and will clear up formatting once I have the Ubuntu machine back on - sorry!

Askubuntu prompts me to run lspci and list output. For the wireless (if it is useful):

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

dmesg says:

```
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
```

/etc/network/interfaces contains

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

which I believe is OK.

The Ubuntu machine appears to connect to the phone hotspot (managed network), but seems unable to resolve any sites.

The tethered data allowance has plenty left and this normally works fine. The ISP/carrier gives a DNS server IP address on connection, there is no fixed one to set.

I tried running

```
sudo dhclient wlp2s0
```

(and sudo service network-manager restart)

It complains the file already exists. There is a symbolic link from /etc/resolve.conf to /run/resolvconf/resolve.conf

If I remove it, it complains that particular link isn't there.
The file content (minus comments) is

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

I don't know if that is a plausible address.. any good ideas?

Comment: You mean `inet` not `inte`, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your phone, when acting as your wifi router, is not providing DNS information automatically.  `lo` is your loopback ethernet adapter, the `/etc/network/interfaces` file is normal. Instead of removing `/etc/resolv.conf` insert `nameserver 8.8.8.8` above the line `nameserver 127.0.0.1`.  You won't need to restart networking, your DNS resolution will be functional at this point, but the correct way is to use systemctl (systemd):

> sudo systemctl restart networking.service
>
> sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service

You may be able to fix your hotspot settings to provide DNS information upon connection, as that would be ideal.